# How to prevent preloading of fragments in viewpager?

Tags: android-fragments

I have 2 fragments in my viewpager.I want to prevent loading of second fragment since in my 2nd frag i am sending request to the server.I tried setOffscreenPageLimit this function but no luck..Please help me with this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When you use ViewPager in Android there is no way to disable the pre-loading of tabs by atleast 1. That means the min for setOffScreenPageLimit is 1. This is to enable the smooth scrolling with ViewPager. 
If your server request is asynchronous then you shouldn't worry about calling the server as it is done in the background thread.